# Efficient way to MapApply for Tensor

Tags: performance-tuning, tensors, map

I need to Map a function with certain arguments $f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ onto a whole tensor.

My current approach looks like

```
n = 400;

ATensor = Table[{# + i, # + i + 1, # + i + 2, # + i + 3} & /@ Range[n], {i, 1, n}];

f[#1, #2, #3, #4] & @@@ ATensor[[#]] & /@ Range[n]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

and I end up getting the desired result within the following computation time on my maschine.

```
{0.0712512, Null}
```

I'd like to be more efficient when mapping the function onto the tensor so I tried to speed up this computation. I noticed that the majority of time is taken while iterating through every single row because mapping the function onto one row just takes a small amount of time.

```
f[#1, #2, #3, #4] & @@@ ATensor[[1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

{0.0001304, Null}
```

Due to the fact that I have to apply functions to tensors with large dimensions I'd like to know if there is a smarter and more efficient way to map the function onto the whole tensor or speed up the iteration through every single row. At this point I am very thankful for any tips on how to improve the computational time.

**UPDATE**

- Fixed the mistake of the indexing mentioned by [thorimur](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286351/81850).
- I implemented the input of [thorimur](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286351/81850) and changed `f[#1, #2, #3, #4] &`
  to `f` with the following speedup (twice as fast)

  ```
  f @@@ ATensor[[#]] & /@ Range[n]; // AbsoluteTiming

  {0.0298548, Null}
  ```
- I also tried to use `Apply[f, ATensor, {2}]` and it give the desired result but it is not faster than my approach but more neat I guess.

  ```
  Apply[f, ATensor, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

  {0.0282078, Null}
  ```
- I tried using `ArrayReduce` aswell and ended up being slower than the first to variants

  ```
  ArrayReduce[Apply[f], ATensor, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming

  {0.190799, Null}
  ```

Comment: First, I suggest using `RepeatedTiming` instead of `AbsoluteTiming` to get more consistent and robust timings. Second, you haven't given us any `f` – Are you sure that it is the mapping and not the actual `f` that will be a performance bottleneck in your computation?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ya my main problem was to efficiently map the function onto the tensor. The function itself is just a numerical integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `f[#1, #2, #3, #4] &` is just `f`—this substitution by itself saves some time—and that `Apply` (`@@@`) has a secret levelspec argument! You want `{2}`, i.e. `Apply[f, ATensor, {2}]`.

Note also that you've accidentally pseudo-0-indexed `ATensor` with the `{i, 0, n}` iterator. This means that you lose a row when writing  `/@ Range[n]`, since `Range[n]` is `{1, ... , n}`, and list indices are likewise 1-indexed (so you lose the last row, not the first). However, you should *never* have to map over indices like this (well, almost never); all your mapping should be doable with `Map` and `Apply` directly, both of which take levelspec args. You may also find functions like `TensorTranspose` and `ArrayReduce` (and, in that context, the operator form `Apply[f]`) helpful. Hope this helps!

Edit, after seeing the edits to the question: turns out `f @@@ ATensor[[#]] & /@ Range[n]` is slightly faster than `Apply[f, ATensor, {2}]`! I'm pretty surprised.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response and your input. You helped me alot. I updated my question and posted the computation time for the adjustments you mentioned. I was not able to implement `TensorTranspose` right away but I will try this aswell in the near future and compare the results.

Comment: May I ask a further question to this topic? In some cases I have a function just like the already mentioned function $f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)$ but this function $g(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,x)$ now depends on a additional parameter $x$ which "remains". So I'd like to map the function onto `ATensor` and evaluate the function just with respect to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$. Am I still able to get rid of the overhead when using `Result[x_] := f[#1, #2, #3, #4, x] & @@@ ATensor[[#]] & /@ Range[n];` for example to achieve a speedup in this case aswell?

Comment: @mathetronaut Hmm, good question! I'm not sure. You might try defining things such that it's actually written `g[x][a,b,c,d]` instead of `g[a,b,c,d,x]`. But simply replacing `g[x][a,b,c,d]` with `g[a,b,c,d,x]` is slower, by itself; instead, if you structure your code such that `g[x][a,b,c,d]` is *directly* what you want it to be, it might be faster, as then you can simply write `g[x] @@@ ATensor[[#]] & /@ Range[n]` for the mapping part, and no extra "intermediate" rewrites have to happen. I think the goal is to have as few rewrites as possible.